# Uncorrect vs. Incorrect; Do the two words have the same meaning?

Tags: dictionaries, archaicisms

I often heard professors at the University I was enrolled in use the word "uncorrect."

The word 'uncorrect' is in some reputable English dictionaries, and conspicuous by its absence in others.

Are people who use the word 'uncorrect' incorrect in the words intended usage?

Or, should the word 'uncorrect' not be used at all?

Additional Information:

Through a brief search of the word 'uncorrect', these are four online dictionaries that publish 'uncorrect' as being a legitimate word. I readily admit, these dictionary resources are not to be relied upon.

The links are as follows:

[www.dictionary.com/browse/uncorrect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncorrect)

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Uncorrect

https://www.yourdictionary.com/uncorrect

https://www.azdictionary.com/what-does-Uncorrect-mean

Comment: Uncorrect is usually incorrect.

Comment: Hi Joe, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to cite specific dictionaries, as I've just checked MW, OALD, CALD/CDO, AHD, LDOCE, MM, CD, Lexico, and OED, and not a single one identifies *uncorrect* as a valid contemporary form.

Comment: Can you explain what the professors meant by this specialized word? You don't mean they used the verb as a substitute for the adjective *incorrect*?

Comment: How old were the professors?

Comment: I will give you an example. Professor Wordsmith said to me bluntly, "Mr. Correct, your assumptions are completely uncorrect!" I was astonished to hear this supposed learned professor use such appalling English.

Comment: As for the age of this particular English professor, he was approximately sixty years old.

Comment: The word has an old navigation meaning. Today, I'd use it informally here: "Your correction was worse. Please uncorrect it." And of course a  mistake may be corrected or uncorrected yet.

Comment: Thanks. Your first link is for a verb usage, not an adjective usage. The second is from a dictionary published in 1913. The third labels it non-standard or archaic. The fourth is not by any stretch a "reputable" dictionary.

Comment: I once had an eccentric high school English teacher who didn't like the Oxford comma, and so we had to leave it out of things we wrote for his class. He also made us use unlined paper.  But everyone else insisted on Oxford commas, so after that semester I never omitted them again. And always used lined paper from then on. I think you have a similar situation here.

Comment: When I use the word 'professors' in the plural form, I am not contending this particular word was used by the majority of my professors. One particular professor used the word uncorrect most often as a substitute for the word incorrect. I knew better than to bring this incorrect word usage to his attention. Otherwise, the word uncorrect was only used on  three or four occasions by two other professors over a four year period.

Comment: I would interpret "uncorrect" as an editor writing "stet".

Comment: Correct answer x incorrect answer;  corrected manuscript x uncorrected manuscript. Agree with @YosefBaskin's view.

Comment: This sounds like Newspeak to me.  Correct is doubleplusgood. Uncorrect is doubleplusungood.